# i want to validate username from database using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i want that when user type username in from fiel it validate from process.php and after validate it show result  in front of name field .
i want that when user select uk from contry it show uk city and if selected india then show india cities how can it possiable with jquery and if any fiel eppty it show an error

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Form Example</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please let us know who you are.",
                email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    label.error { width: 250px; display: inline; color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
<!-- The Name form field -->
    <div id='name'> </div>
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Username</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
<!-- The Email form field -->
    <div id='email'> </div>
    <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/> 
    <br>
<!-- The Country form field -->
    <div id='Select_option'> </div>
    <label for="country" id="country_label">Contry</label>  
<select name="contry">
<option value="uk">uk</option>
<option value="india">india</option>
</select>

    <br>
<!-- The Country form field -->
    <div id='uk_city'> </div>
    <label for="ukcity" id="ukcity_label">uk city</label>  
<select name="uk_city">
<option value="u0">u0</option>
<option value="u1">u1</option>
</select>

    <br>
<!-- The Country form field -->
    <div id='ind_city'> </div>
    <label for="indcity" id="indcity_label">ind city</label>  
<select name="ind_city">
<option value="i0">i0</option>
<option value="i1">i1</option>
</select>

    <br>


<!-- The Submit button -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
<!-- We will output the results from process.php here -->
<div id="results"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn PHP, MySQL, then find and read some examples on Login forms/scripts here first. If you believe, that someone else will do all the work instead of you, you are wrong.

Comment: What problem does the code you posted have? SO is not a code factory, you can't give a bunch of requirements and a piece of code and expect to have your work done here.

Answer (score 1):

First, most validation should be done i js to save server roundtrips for easy things like empty fields or invalid input (letters in an age field).

Then use ajax to validate the form returning a json object containing either success = true or success = false along with an array with objects indicating which fields are in error and what the error is.

You could avoid posting the form bu using $.ajax command instead and only sending the fields you need to validate.

Also remember to not trust js validation, only server side validation is immune to tampering.

Normally you create a server side session where you set logged in to true to prevent the user to bypass login bu going directly to specific page.

Comment: ok dude send me validation code of ajax by simpling sending dta at process.php and gett result frpm process.php

Comment: You're still expecting to have your work done by others. David has given valuable advice here, you could try working on it yourself and come back with a specific question.

Comment: ok thanks for telling me just tel me that is this possiable with jquery or not

Comment: @user1206641: Please take the pains to read about JQuery. There are several JQuery form validators available online to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yes it's possible with jquery, I suggest looking up the ajax method of jquery for the call to the server and val() and is() methods för field validation client side.